# Turning the faucet just a little bit makes the water too cold?

Tags: water, shower, faucet

When I'm showering the faucet is usually turned well towards the hot side. Everything is fine and dandy. But sometimes I realize that the water is too hot so I turn the faucet *ever so slightly* to the right to make it just a tad less hot.

But within 15 seconds, the water has gone from boiling hot to decently cold making me quickly shoot the faucet back to the left. I imagine that if I don't turn the faucet  back left within 30 seconds the water would probably be freezing cold.

What causes this? How can I fix it? Is it not possible to turn the faucet ever so slightly and get a moderately warm temperature?

Comment: Single handle mixing valve?  what model or manufacturer?

Comment: What kind of water heater do you have--tank or tankless?

Comment: What kind of shower head do you have--standard 2.5 gal/min or lower flow ( 2.0 gal/min or even 1.0 gal/min)? Tankless water heaters are designed to shut off if the hot water flow decreases below a certain value. The flow can drop below the cut-off value with a low flow shower head.